# Direct all links on one page up one folder level

Tags: html, directory

I have a site in which I want to put a series of pages in a folder, but am having issues with styles, images, and header files referenced in the sub pages not being directed correctly. I can't simply direct each link on the page up a level because I am using php header and footer files that are linked from root level pages as well. If I had my image links in the header direct up a level it would break my root level pages.

I'd also prefer not to use absolute links as that creates complications (the site is nested within local host and I'd have to rewrite all of the absolute links when the site is uploaded to my server).

Is there a simple way to put something in the head of a page that would redirect each link within a page up one level?

Example:

Both

```
htdocs/mysite/index.php
```

and

```
htdocs/mysite/members/user.php
```

need to reference

```
htdocs/mysite/styles/styles.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the HTML Base tag?

> The `<base>` tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in
>   a document.
>
> There can be at maximum one `<base>` element in a document, and it must
>   be inside the `<head>` element.

Try testing it and see if that helps:

```
<base href="/htdocs/mysite/" target="_blank">
```